two Win10 OS on different physical ssd device
I currently have two SSDs installed on my computer. On one SSD, I have Windows 10 installed for work-related tasks and office work. Recently, I acquired a new SSD specifically to store and run games. So I installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 on this new SSD. However, even after completing the installation process, I'm still able to see folders from my other SSD device. This situation raises a couple of questions: Why are these folders appearing on my new SSD, and is there a way to hide them to ensure that my gaming SSD remains clutter-free and dedicated solely to gaming purposes?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65Fk5zLB.png


after completing the installation process, I'm still able to see folders from my other SSD device. This situation raises a couple of questions: Why are these folders appearing on my new SSD

An OS does not have exclusive claim on its storage devices. As long as the SSD is connected to the computer as a whole, it will show up on every OS that happens to be running on that computer.

is there a way to hide them

Run diskmgmt.msc, then either unassign drive letters from the individual volumes, or 'Offline' the entire disk (both can be done by right-clicking the corresponding part of the bottom pane).

One note: even if folders are visible, NTFS still has security permissions. Given that the user guid is not on this window, those folders are likely going to give an access denied. Trying to open them anyway may screw up the other OS.
